# Running ionic app on android device with sdk 15 (4.0.4)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator, device

I am trying to run my ionic app on an android device using SDK 15 (4.0.4). It installs, but when it opens there is a black screen and then it crashes.
The app runs in the emulator, so I think it has something to do with the fact that it is using an old OS. I have read in two places that it isn't possible to build/run on a phone lower than SDK 21. Is this true?

I am using:

```
4.0.4/SDK 15.
Samsung Galaxy Note I717
Ionic Framework
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official ionic blog](http://blog.ionic.io/market-share-movement-android/) ionic does only support Android versions >= 4.1 so your app crashing on 4.0.4 is quite expected.